# LED Strip not lighting up smoothly

Tags: led-strip

I recently purchased a LED strip off amazon along with an external power supply, hoping to be able to control the LED's with an Arduino. Unfortunately after testing with the external power supply, the LED strip does not seem to light up smoothly like they do in the test with the Arduino([video example](https://youtu.be/Bb5h0_FxUZ4)). I am not an electrical expert so I don't exactly know how to explain this one and it puzzles me as to why this happens. If any more information is needed let me know.

After adding a capacitor to the circuit The same problem seems to persist.[Video example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X794-PRWj30). The program shown in the video example is set to turn all of the LEDs blue. A link to the program can be found in the comments below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foNVKX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Do note that is not the exact LED stip.

After some further testing, the Led's will stop changing colors and hold their last color if the data pin coming from the Arduino is removed. Is there any chance that the power supply could be affecting the data pin and what is sent to the ic's?

Here is the [LED strip](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K7UHPEC)

[image]

and this is the [external power suply](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HYXAG04)

[image]

Comment: Wasn't able to have more than 2 links, but here is the LED strip   https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00K7UHPEC/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1 and this is the external power suply https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01HYXAG04/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: The supply may be too noisy. Add a 1000uF cap at the strip to smooth it out.

Comment: I head home from school in a few weeks so I can pick one up then and try it out. Is there any way to test if the supply is in fact to noisy in the mean time? Thanks for the response.

Comment: An oscilloscope can show any noise or ripple. Especially under load (i.e. connected to your led strip). The supply is a switching regulator, while the Arduino 5V is provided by usb or regulated down with a linear regulator,  very smooth. The switching supply will have some ripple from switching and the ac regulation.

Comment: Your video link is broken.  Modify your program to only activate the first dozen or so LEDs which will reduce the power requirement and see what happens.  A question like this needs to include full detail including your code.

Comment: Same problem occurs at only 20 LED's, but not quite as severe. the code is very basic and I can assure you is correct and sets all of the LED's to the color blue. It uses Adafruits Neopixel library

Comment: That's a rather disingenuous thing to say - the video link only works because you just changed it.  The original link does not.  With only a few LEDs activated, either your power supply is completely fake, or else your code is wrong.  **POST YOUR CODE**.

Comment: Here is the edited code http://pastebin.com/Gh7XYiHd

Comment: Measure the Vdc and Vac on the strip please under fault conditions and Ok condition. Use twisted wire with ground for PWM control to improve signal integrity if that is a cause.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow exactly what you are asking

Comment: do you have a multimeter? (DMM)

Comment: yes, I do have one

Comment: Also note that your logic signals driving the cable must be very close the LEDstrip with short leads driving clocks with MHz speeds and xx nanoseconds of rise time.  See here http://jeelabs.org/book/1450d/

Comment: Then check you DC supply as I requested for DC and AC ripple on strip

Comment: I'm getting 5.5V on DC, nothing is standing out to me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was solved by connecting one of the ground pins to the Arduino. Thanks everyone for their help!